# AngularJS form field in ng-repeat and sum column

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have dynamic form fields like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="wspStaffTbl in staff_codes">
     {{wspStaffTbl.Staff_Type}}
     <input type="text" ng-model="wspStaffTbl.Permanent" ng-change="updateTotal()">
     <input type="text" ng-model="wspStaffTbl.Contract" ng-change="updateTotal()">
     <input type="text" ng-model="wspStaffTbl.Total">
</div>
```

Where staff_codes are recived by my database. I want to sum each Permanent and Contract and put it in Total whenever user put value in wspStaffTbl.Permanent or `wspStaffTbl.Contract`.

I tried this

```
<input type="text" ng-value="(wspStaffTbl.Permanent)--(wspStaffTbl.Contract)" ng-model="wspStaffTbl.Total">
```

It working fine but if the fields already have some data (eg. in edit form) it won't update total. So I need this in my controller:

```
$scope.updateTotal= function(){
       $scope.wspStaffTbl.Total =  $scope.wspStaffTbl.Permanent + $scope.wspStaffTbl.Contract;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems

(i) Change input type from text to number,

```
  <div ng-controller="app.invoice" class="container">
  <div ng-repeat="wspStaffTbl in staff_codes">
     {{wspStaffTbl.Staff_Type}}
     <input type="number" ng-model="wspStaffTbl.Permanent" ng-change="updateTotal(wspStaffTbl)">
     <input type="number" ng-model="wspStaffTbl.Contract" ng-change="updateTotal(wspStaffTbl)">
     <input type="number" ng-model="wspStaffTbl.Total">
</div>
```

(ii) Pass the variable on ng-change and add it to the total,

```
$scope.updateTotal= function(val){
        val.Total =  val.Permanent + val.Contract;
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/qp2d34r2/9/)**

Comment: seems to be working but it concat the value instead of adding

Comment: may be it is issue with input type i will check

Answer (score 0):

**As suggested in one answer and taking reference from it**, if you take number fields, it is easy to calculate the sum of the fields.

The issue you are getting as you said,

"**It working fine but if the fields already have some data (eg. in edit form) it won't update total**"

**My answer mainly solves your issue which you are facing while editing, to initialize the total values with the values of the input.**

This can be solved by initialising the `total field` using `ng-init`.

**`ng-init="updateTotal(code)"`**

Here is the solved snippet,

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div ng-repeat="code in staff_codes">
     <input type="number" ng-model="code.Permanent" ng-change="updateTotal(code)">
     <input type="number" ng-model="code.Contract" ng-change="updateTotal(code)">
     <input type="number" ng-model="code.Total" ng-init="updateTotal(code)">
</div>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.code = {}

  $scope.staff_codes = [{
    name: 'Test',
    Permanent: 10,
    Contract: 20,
    Total:0
  }, {
    name: 'Obama',
    Permanent: 15,
    Contract: 35,
      Total:0
  }, {
    name: 'Trump',
    Permanent: 35,
    Contract: 55,
      Total:0
  }]; 

$scope.updateTotal= function(code){

        code.Total =  code.Permanent + code.Contract

    }


});
</script>

</body>
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hy34t6bn/)

Comment: who down voted it, and what is the reason for the downvote. I know, downvoters will be ready for the downvote, thats the reason I mentioned everything in my answer, please read the answer once before downvoting it.

Comment: i did downvote, i dont see any difference from the answer i posted, also you copied and changed the code

Comment: @Sajeetharan, please read my first line, I mentioned it is from your answer, please be fair.

Comment: i do accept you mentioned it, but you could have posted this as a comment

Comment: do you have `ng-init` in your answer first? you dont have it. I just added it to fulfill his requirement. now you edited and added `ng-init` after my  answer.

Comment: i did upvote most of your answers , no it was there in the fiddle dude

Comment: I have seen it bro, if not, I am not a kind of person, who simply copies the code from others.

Comment: even check your answer, it does not have `ng-init` in it.

Comment: That is what i am saying, instead of copying and adding ng-init, you could have posted in comment. ok will remove the downvote

Comment: I dont know, I can comment an answer. I felt I can share something more from my amswer. so, I added as an answer.

Comment: your edit clearly shows your changed fiddle link bro. :)

Comment: @sanu, thanks for reading the conversation instead of ignoring the downvoted answer, checked my snippet with ng-init?

Comment: @Sajeetharan, please look at the comment `your edit clearly shows your changed fiddle `, also you said that, you will revert back your downvote.